# Accessing a protected data member of a super class' friend in the sub classes function

Tags: c++, inheritance

There are three classes, A, B, C;
Class A is friends with B, B has a protected data member. Class C inherits publicly from Class A. Can I access those protected data members of B by initializing a B object in a function of C?

If not how would I Go about accessing the values of B in C functions?

Comment: Secrets declares Security Manager to be a `friend`. Malicious Class extends Security Manager. Should Malicious Class have access to Secrets' secrets?

Comment: `friend`s are a part of C++, a core part of the language. But 9 times out of 10, having to declare `friend`s is a result of improper class design, that's not fully thought out, and the correct solution is not to declare `friend`s all over the place, but to redesign the classes with formal, bullet-proof APIs that callers can use to do what's needed. What's asked here is too generic, vague, and nebulous. If a concrete, specific example is provided, it's a near certainty that a few suggestions can be made to tweak the classes making `friend` declarations unnecessary.

Comment: If you can give a [mcve] of what you are trying to do, people can propose concrete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the protected members of B directly in C but you could introduce a protected method in A that gets/sets the protected member in B; since C is derived from A you could access the protected get/set methods in A from C, see example below. Probably best to think about the overall design though.

```
class A
{
protected:
    int getValueOfB(B& b) { return b.protectedValue; }
    void setValueInB(B& b, int value) { b.protectedValue = value; }
};

class C
{
    void doSomething()
    {
       B b;
       setValueInB(b, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`friend` are NOT inherited.
In the same way `friend` of `friend` are NOT `friend`.

As alternative, [passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) might help in your case:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    struct Key{
        friend class B; // no longer in class A.
    private:
        Key() = default;
        Key(const Key&) = default;
    };
    // ...
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    void secret(Key /*, ...*/) { /*..*/ }
};

class B
{
public:
    void foo(C& c) {
         c.secret(A::Key{}); // Access C private thanks to "private" key from A.
    }
};
```